# how to resolve the 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar' error in xamarin?

Tags: android, xml, xamarin.android, android-theme

using xamarin to build an app, the following is the error i get while building  **Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'** I get this when trying to inherit from Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar. I already have xamarin.android.support.v4, xamarin.android.support.v7.appcompat in reference and using Xamarin.Forms 2.3.0.46
.Below is the Style.xml code im using

```
<style name="AppThemeSliderToolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:colorPrimary">#00d1ff</item>
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#40c5e9</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Any solution to this error?

Answer (score 0):

You have to open this tag on themes.xml instead of styles.xml and change "style name" to "theme name"

Comment: This answer is wrong, according to [Android docs - Styles and Themes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme): `"<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">"` and `"For example, here is the declaration for a custom theme. It would go in an XML file under res/values (typically res/values/styles.xml)"`